# How to run an application in headless mode?

Tags: command-line, display, gui, headless

Let's say I have a desktop app with GUI. I switch to the text terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3, I login and I try to run this app. I get an error message indicating that display is not available.

The question is - How can I reproduce the above situation using the terminal application (gnome-terminal, guake, terminator, xterm, etc...) ? How can make it think that display is not available even though it is?

Answer (score 3):

If you are on X11, do `unset DISPLAY`

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
$ xterm  #works
$ unset DISPLAY
$ xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

Comment: works for me. Thank you.

Comment: you can click to accept the answer